# Ahead-Of-Time Compilation doesn't work pushing an element in providers variable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot, aot

I'm trying to get up and running with angular ahead-of-time compilation (AOT) that doesn't work pushing an element in providers variable in @NgModule.

```
...    
const providers: any[] = [
       someService
     ];

if (environment.useMockBackend) {
    providers.push({
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MockHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true
    });
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: providers
})
export class CoreModule {
...
}
```

But it works without ahead of time. however should we wait the next version of Angular being fixed of AOT? or is there something possible to solve that way?

### **UPDATE:**

for more clarifying, providers property in NgModule decorator doesn't work for MockHttpInterceptor after initialized, on the contrary, it will work if we modify this similar to as the following:

```
const providers: any[] = [
  ReviewService,
  {
    provide: environment.useMockBackend ? HTTP_INTERCEPTORS : '',
    useClass: environment.useMockBackend ? MockHttpInterceptor : '',
    multi: true
  }
];
```

However, it is not good practice what we do mostly

Comment: how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: I updated the context for more clarifying, please see the update bullet. Thanks :)

Comment: Angular ngc needs to know which components to compile. To do so, it doesn't execute the code, it does by parsing and locating specific constructs. This requires avoiding a few patterns, like assigning a function expression to a const, but use a function declaration instead.

Comment: @AndréWerlang my understanding of your comment meaning that it is hoisting. isn't it?